# Iterating array-elements as single values inside collection-document (Meteor)

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to create an online-list for a chat. Whenever a person moves into a room, his nickname gets pushed into the array inRoom, when he leaves it gets pulled out again. This works fine so far. Displaying the arrays on the actual list confuses me though.

I need the names to be separated in order to take put them in anchor tags since those names are url-parameters.

A room-document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "crsEES5d22uYJiqDZ",
  "name": "Room",
  "roomdesc": " ",
  "inRoom": [name1, name2, name3],
  "createdAt": "2019-06-08T12:39:51.382Z",
  "owner": "Kuroki"
}
```

I have a helper to get the array. I use getParam to get the name of the room in order to find the right one.

```
Template.onlineliste.helpers({
  roomData() {
    var name = FlowRouter.getParam('name');
    return Channels.find({name:name}, {sort: {createdAt: 1}})
  },
});
```

Then I tried to iterate which of course will show the array as a whole and not every name as single value

```
<template name="onlineliste">
    {{#each roomData}}
    {{inRoom}} 
    {{/each}}
  </template>
```

Could someone show me how to iterate the single values of the array so they will display like

- Name 1
- Name 2
- Name 3

instead of Name1, Name 2, Name 3

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone show me how to iterate the single values of the array so they will display like ...

The field `inRoom` is itself an array, so you need a second `each`:

```html
<template name="onlineliste">
  {{#each room in roomData}}
    <ul>
      {{#each name in room.inRoom}} 
        <li>{{name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

If there is anyway only one room to be displayed you can even change your code to return the current single room:

```js
Template.onlineliste.helpers({
  roomData() {
    var name = FlowRouter.getParam('name');
    return Channels.findOne({name:name}})
  },
});
```

which returns only one room document by name and does not require to be iterated. Then you can access it via the following:

```html
<template name="onlineliste">
  {{#with roomData}}
    <ul>
      {{#each name in this}} 
        <li>{{name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

Comment: I think the reason why this won't work on my problem is that {{name}} doesn't refer to the values of the array. I tried it with find and findOne.

Comment: Did you `console.log(Channels.findOne({name:name}}))` to verify it returns anything? And yes, the `name` value is correct - this is a blaze equivalent of `for (let element in iterable) { ... }` where the value `name` is assigned the context of the current element of the iteration.

Comment: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: Channels is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1``` It says, when I try this console.log. But it's weird, since I can return the array as a whole already by doing {{roomData.inRoom}} for example. However, if I use the findOne-option console.log responds with```{{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey value```

Comment: This is why you need to use `with` on `findOne` as in the last code snippet I posted. Please try to use this.

Comment: I did. It was the same error: ```Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.``` I even copied the snippet. I even tried it on a blank page to see if some other code was interfering but the same outcome. If you're super-sure thats the way to do it, I suspect the fault must lay somewhere else. I will try to find it. Thank you for your time.